# Using an SQLCipher database in a persistent store

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlcipher

I've gotten to the point where I can create an encrypted copy of my database with SQLCipher, now I'm trying to integrate it into my project. I've tried using the following code in my app delegate to unencrypt the database...

```
   NSString *databasePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"encrypted.db"];

if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char* key = [@"BIGSecret" UTF8String];
    sqlite3_key(db, key, strlen(key));
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master;", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // password is correct, or, database has been initialized
        NSLog(@"correct password");

    } else {
        // incorrect password!
        NSLog(@"incorrect password");
    }
```

Then later at the persistent store, I use the following code.

```
if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"encrypted.db"];


NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
```

The first time I load the program after creating the database, I'll get a "correct password" log, but anytime after that I get an "incorrect password", but the database is still usable, which leads me to believe that the database is being overwritten or something.

Comment: Alright, it's definitely at the persistent store coordinator (PSC) where it's getting messed up, if I insert the code to open the DB right before the PSC it works, then if I enter it right after that line of code where the PSC is defined, it gives the incorrect password log

Comment: Alright, now I'm leaning towards trying to implement a manager class for the database like this one:
https://github.com/sqlcipher/SQLCipherManager

unless there is a simpler way to just fix the persistent store coordinator messing things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoreData doesn't work directly with SQLCipher, as it's using SQLite from the device directly. You could potentially take a look at the Encrypted Core Data project, (https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data) which uses SQLCipher and a custom NSIncrementalStore to provide similar features.